# XUnit tests don't run (endless loop)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, xunit, xunit.net

I have a "EMPTY" "[Fact]" / UnitTest method that doesn't run.

- Win10, x64.
- .NET Core SDK 2.2.104
- xUnit proj includes a .NET Standard 2.0 lib
- VS 2017 15.9.8

Click run all tests or try to debug and the green progress bar at the top in VS just keeps doing it waiting green pan. I have tried deleting all NuGet packages, clean builds etc.

Is there some other cache folder I could try deleting? This is road blocking me.

Example:

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace Audio.Test
{
    public class Test_AudioSystem
    {
        [Fact]
        public void GetAllAudioDevices()
        {
            // does nothing...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a dummy line like this: `var x = 0;`?

Comment: Did you add the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` nuget package to your project?

Comment: Can you share the log with us?

Comment: Somehow a .NET Core / UWP or .NET Standard 2.0 lib is messing up xUnit as I'm building out all my libs into a single bin path as it helps with mixed C# and C/C++ debugging.

Comment: Think System.Collections.Immutable.dll from a .NET Framework project might be the issue.

Comment: Ok found the issue. Have Newtonsoft.Json.dll from a .NET Framework project in the same directory as my test libraries. This is somehow causing an endless loop. The question is does this bug happend with a .NET Core version of Newtonsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the issue. Have Newtonsoft.Json.dll from a .NET Framework project in the same directory as my test libraries. This is somehow causing an endless loop. The question is does this bug happen with a .NET Core version of Newtonsoft.